# Vue - redirect user after survey completation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have this code in a method of my vue app

```js
    showNext() {
      if( this.n < this.$store.getters.quiz.length ){
        this.n++
      } else {
        this.stopTimer();
        this.$router.push({path: '/result'});
      }
    }
```

I have an array of questions and I'm incrementing a counter after each question is answered from the user with the code above. I want to redirect the user if he answer to all the questions so I have put an `if` statement to try achiving this. The problem is that when all the questions are answered, the user will be not redirected as I was expecting. How I can fix this?

Comment: What is start n?

Comment: `n` is a variable that when the app run is set to 0

Comment: set initial value of `n` to 1

Comment: @IgorMoraru why if the array index starts from 0?

Comment: because the index of the array will never equal to its length, so your else block is never reached

Comment: ok, since I need that the `n` is set to 0 when the app start I can simply do `this.$store.getters.quiz.length - 1`; Thank you for the tip!